# PHP curl() Headers bad request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to figure out why pasing a custom header is resulting in a 400 BAD REQUEST from the server.

```
    $headers = array(
                    'API KEY: asdf',
                    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'stuff');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './tmp/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '0000');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '0.0.0.0');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I thought that using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER would add a custom header to the request, but I'm now wondering whether it's simply overriding everything else I set?

Comment: `API KEY` doesn't seem like a valid http header.

Comment: Maybe this will work `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'X-API KEY: asdf' ) );`, not sure.

Comment: API KEY is supposed to be a custom header, and I tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'X-API KEY: asdf' ) );` with the same result.

Comment: While a space is a valid character in a header name according to RFC 822, have you tried it without a space? It certainly is unusual, if not (technically) incorrect. Also, the use of X- as a prefix has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There are more reasons a server will give a 400 response than just a header value. Without more information about the endpoint it's difficult to say what's causing the 400 response. With the exception of the extra "," in the headers array in the example the code looks okay. [cURL Options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)